# Why is it so bad to read data from a database "owned" by a different microservice

Tags: architecture, web-services, soa, microservices, modularization

I have recently read this excellent article on the microservice architecture: http://www.infoq.com/articles/microservices-intro

It states that when you load a web page on Amazon, then 100+ microservices cooperate to serve that page.

That article describes that all communication between microservices can only go through an API. My question is why it is so bad to say that all database writes can only go through an API, but you are free to read directly from the databases of the various micro services. One could for example say that only a few database views are accessible outside the micro service so that the team maintaining the micro service know that as long as they keep these views intact then they can change the database structure of their micro service as much as they want.

Am I missing something here? Is there some other reason why data should only be read via an API?

Needless to say, my company is significantly smaller than Amazon (and always will be) and the maximum number of users we can ever have is about 5 million.

Comment: One more general factor not mentioned in the answers is that when written to the database, local caching, even simple O/R mapping, might yield stale data when immediately accessing the database. If you consider bypassing the µservice API for speed reasons, it well may be that one took the µservice architecture too far.

Comment: When allowing database reads every detail of the database becomes part of the public API. I wouldn't want to maintain compatibility on such a complex API.

Comment: But in that case doesn't the view simply become part of the API, at least for semantic purposes? It's just a matter of what you are calling the API and what that forces you to maintain. (Usually a layer above the database is easier to keep consistent.)

Comment: I agree that the view would simply be a form of an API. I think most people answering this question do not read my idea about using views as a level of abstraction. I understand, though that keeping the view intact if one changed the database technology would be a major challenge, but I am willing to bet on that we will not need to change our database technology for the next 5 years. Also, performance will not be a problem with just 5 mill users. So, given our size, I thank I will go for this solution, even though the answers here seem to indicate that I am heading straight to a world of pain.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Databases are not very good at information hiding, which is quite plausible, because their job is to actually expose information. But this makes them a lousy tool when it comes to encapsulation. Why do you want encapsulation?

Scenario: you tie a couple of components to an RDBMS directly, and you see one particular component becoming a performance bottle-neck for which you might want to denormalize the database, but you can't because all other components would be affected. You may even realize that you'd be better off with a document store or a graph database than with an RDBMS. If the data is encapsulated by a small API, you have a realistic chance to reimplement said API any way you need. You can transparently insert cache layers and what not.

Fumbling with the storage layer directly from the application layer is the diametrical opposite of what the [dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) suggests to do.

Comment: This is a great point! One thing that makes me less concerned is that Postgres now has support for both document store and RDBMS (http://withouttheloop.com/articles/2014-09-30-postgresql-nosql/). Your point is still valid, though, and I will consider it carefully.

Comment: It shouldn't make you less concerned @David just because a tool can do something doesn't mean that changing it won't break a lot of things. That's the point of having a degree of separation - you can completely change the data behind an API without changing what the user sees. I'm speaking as a databaser here... as long as what the client sees is the same you can change the backend as much as you want.

Comment: @David While this is interesting news, it's quite irrelevant for the scenario I described. If you change your DB schema from a relational to a document based one, it will have the same impact on all those depending on it: you will have to rewrite all queries. There's also the nightmare of having to deploy all these changes at once, so that compatibility between components is maintained across the system.

Comment: @back2dos Please note this part of my question: "One could for example say that only a few database views are accessible outside the micro service so that the team maintaining the micro service know that as long as they keep these views intact then they can change the database structure of their micro service as much as they want." Shouldn't it be possible to keep a view intact while changing the tables the view selects from from RDBMS to document based?

Comment: @David: Restricting access to a few well defined views arguably means to build another API, with some of the benefits that come with it. As long as it's just views, you're however restricted to read-only access. And having a component depend on both the service API and the view API makes it very fragile. So if you're making a component depend on the views, you've predetermined it to be read-only or high-maintenance. I smell technical debt here. Also you may want to add horizontal partitioning in a way that your database doesn't allow you to.

Comment: @David: But more broadly: Using an API that you fully control and can extend and that you're able to easily implement (which is not quite trivial with the postgres wire protocol acting as part of the contract) makes the choice of the database an implementation detail. And good architecture encapsulates decisions as implementation details that are prevented from leaking into the rest of the system. That's what the dependency inversion principle is all about.

Comment: @back2dos I agree that it is not optimal, but what it allows me to do is to write an SQL select query for data mining or rapid prototyping purposes, which selects across microservices. This means that a person, with just some SQL knowledge can gain insights into our data without having to know how to program. It is also much faster than having to do the selecting across microservices in a programming language.

Comment: @David: In the long run it's more important how easy it is to change code than how easy it is to write it. Architecture does not say "you shouldn't write code in such and such way", it says "if you do, you will suffer terrible nightmares trying to maintain it". If you're talking prototypes, then maintenance is not a requirement. Go ahead. A prototype should prove a point as easily as possible. But when trying to integrate all the proven points to a system without having it devolve into Sisyphean self-induced torture, you're better off going the extra mile.

Comment: THose SQL queries by 3rd parties just fill me with foreboding and gloom.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt

Answer (score 61):

What is more important and significant about a microservice: its API or its database schema?  The API, because that is its contract with the rest of the world.  The database schema is simply a convenient way of storing the data managed by the service, hopefully organised in a way that optimises the microservice´s performance.  The development team should be free to reorganise that schema - or switch to an entirely different datastore solution - at any time.  The rest of the world should not care.  The rest of the world cares when the API changes, because the API is the contract.

Now, if you go peeking into their database

- You add an unwanted dependency on their schema.  They cannot change it without having an impact on your service.
- You add unwanted and unpredictable load to their internals.
- The performance of your own service will be affected by the performance of their database (they will be trying to optimise their **service** to perform well for clients and their database to perform well only for their service)
- You are tying your implementation to a schema which may well not accurately and distinctively represent the resources in their data store - it may have extra details which are only needed to track internal state or satisfy their particular implementation (which you should not care about).
- You may unwittingly destroy or corrupt the state of their service (and they will not know you are doing this)
- You may update/delete/remove resources from their database without them knowing this has happened.

The last two points may not happen if you are only granted read access, but the other points are more than a good enough reason.  Shared databases are a bad thing.

It is common for less experienced developers (or those who do not learn) to see the database as more important than the service, to see the database as the **real** thing and the service just a way of getting to it.  That is the wrong way round.

Comment: Please note that all of the above points are valid even if you are the only developer working on the whole project.  Managing a complex project, even by yourself, invokes all of these concerns.

Answer (score 16):

Microservice Architecture is hard to describe but the best way to think about it is a marriage between Component Oriented Architecture and Service Oriented Architecture.  Software as a suite is composed of many small business components with a very specific business domain responsibility.  Their interface to the outside world either in provided services or required services is through an API of clearly defined services.

Writing to and even reading from a database that is outside of your components business domain is against this style of architecture.

The primary reason for this is that an API provided through a service by another software component has the reasonable expectation that the API will most likely be backwards compatible as new releases of the service providing component become available.  If I am the developer of a "providing" component then I only have to worry about backwards compatibility to my API.  If I know that there are three other development teams that wrote custom queries against my database directly then my job has become much more complicated.

Even worse, maybe that other team that wrote these is mid sprint in a critical project and they can't accept this change now from your component.  Now software development for your component on a business domain that you own is being driven by development on another business domain.

Full interaction through services reduce coupling between various software components so situations like this do not occur so frequently. When it comes to other components using a View in the database, then you have more capability to make the View backwards compatible if anybody else wrote queries against it.  I still feel however that this should be the exception case and only should be done for perhaps reporting or batch processing where an application will need to read in enormous amounts of data.

Clearly this works well in large distributed teams where development teams are separated out by business domain like Amazon.  If you are a small development shop you can still benefit by this model, especially if you need to ramp up for a big project quickly, but also if you have to deal with vendor software.

Answer (score 7):

Over the last 20 years I've seen a few large modular database designs and I've seen the scenario suggested by David quite a few times now where applications have write access to their own schema/set of tables and read access to another schema/set of tables. Most often this data that an application/module gets read-only access to could be described as **"master data"**.

In that time I have not seen the problems that prior answers are suggesting I should have seen so I think it is worth having a closer look at the points raised in the previous answers in more detail.

> Scenario: you tie a couple of components to an RDBMS directly, and you see one particular component becoming a performance bottle-neck

I agree with this comment except this is also an argument for have a copy of the data locally for the microservice to read. That is, **most mature databases support replication** and so without any developer effort the "master data" can be physically replicated to the microservice database if that is desired or needed.

Some might recognise this in older guise as an "Enterprise database" replicating core tables to a "Departmental database". A point here is that generally it is good if a database does this for us with built in replication of changed data (deltas only, in binary form and at minimal cost to the source database).

Conversely, when our database choices do not allow this 'off the shelf' replication support then we can get into a situation where we want to push  "master data" out to the microservice databases and this can result in a significant amount of developer effort and also be a substantially less efficient mechanism.

> might want to denormalize the database, but you can't because all other components would be affected

To me this statement is just not correct. Denormalisation is an "additive" change and not a "breaking change" and no application should break due to denormalisation.

The only way this break an application is where application code uses something like "select * ..." and does not handle an extra column. To me that would be a bug in the application?

How can denormalisation break an application? Sounds like FUD to me.

> Schema dependency:

Yes, the application now has a dependency on the database schema and the implication is that this ought to be a major problem. While adding any extra dependency is obviously not ideal my experiance is that a dependency on the database schema has not been a problem 
so why might that be the case? Have I just been lucky?

### Master data

The schema that we typically might want a microservice to have read-only access to is most commonly what I'd describe as "**master data**" for the enterprise. It has the core data that is essential to the enterprise.

Historically this means the schema we add the dependency on is
both mature and stable (somewhat fundamental to the enterprise and unchanging).

### Normalisation

If 3 database designers go and design a normalised db schema they'll end up at the same design. Ok, there might be some 4NF/5NF variation but not much. What's more there are a series of questions that the designer can ask to validate the model so the designer can be confident that they got to 4NF (Am I too optimistic? Are people struggling getting to 4NF?).

**update:** By **4NF** here I mean all tables in the schema got to their highest normal form up to 4NF (all tables got normalised appropriately up to 4NF).

I believe the normalisation design process is why database designers are generally comfortable with the idea of depending on a normalised database schema.

The process of normalisation gets the DB design to a known "correct" design and the variations from there ought to be denormalisation for performance.

1. There can be variations based on DB types supported (JSON, ARRAY,
   Geo type support etc)
2. Some might argue for variation based on 4NF/5NF
3. We exclude physical variation (because that doesn't matter)
4. We restrict this to OLTP design and not DW design because
   those are the schemas we want to grant read-only access to

If 3 programmers where given a design to implement (as code) the expectation would be for 3 different implementations (potentially very different).

To me there is potentially a question of "faith in normalisation".

### Breaking schema changes?

Denormalisation, adding columns, alter columns for bigger storage, extending the design with new tables etc are all non-breaking changes and DB designers who got to 4th normal form will be confident of that.

Breaking changes are obviously possible by dropping columns/tables or making a breaking type change. Possible yes, but in practical terms I've not experienced any problems here at all. Perhaps because it is understood what breaking changes are and these have been well managed?

I'd be interested to hear cases of breaking schema changes in the context of shared read-only schema's.

> What is more important and significant about a microservice: its API or its database schema? The API, because that is its contract with the rest of the world.

While I agree with this statement I think there is an important caveat that we might hear from an Enterprise Architect which is **"Data lives forever"**. That is, while the API might be the most important thing the data is also rather important to the enterprise as a whole and it will be important for a very long time.

For example, once there is a requirement to populate the **Data Warehouse** for **Business intelligence** then the schema and CDC support become important from the business reporting perspective irrespective of the API.

## Issues with API's?

Now if API's were perfect and easy all the points are moot as we'd always choose an API rather than have local read-only access. So the motivation for even considering local read-only access is that there might be some problems using API's that local access avoids.

```
What motivates people to desire local read-only access?
```

### API optimisation:

**LinkedIn** have an interesting presentation (from 2009) on the issue of optimising their API and why it is important to them at their scale. http://www.slideshare.net/linkedin/building-consistent-restful-apis-in-a-highperformance-environment

In short, once an API has to support many different use cases it can easily get into the situation where it supports one use case optimally and the rest rather poorly from a network perspective and database perspective.

If the API does not have the same sophistication as LinkedIn then you can easily get the scenarios where:

- The API fetches much more data than you need (wasteful)
- Chatty API's where you have to call the API many times

Yes, we can add caching to API's of course but ultimately the API call is a remote call and there are a series of optimisations available to developers when the data is local.

I suspect there is a set of people out there who might add it up as:

- Low cost replication of master data to microservice database (at no development cost and technically efficient)
- Faith in Normalisation and the resilience of applications to schema changes
- Ability to easily optimise every use case and potentially avoid chatty/wasteful/inefficient remote API calls
- Plus some other benefits in terms of constraints and coherent design

This answer has got way too long. 
Apologies!!

Comment: Adding a column generally breaks applications. If you have "salary" the application which sums all the salaries breaks when a new column "salary_currency" is introduced.

Comment: Really?  Depends on your definition of "breaks" I suppose.  If the app was in production and operating as expected without a "salary_currency" why would you consider that application now broken?

Comment: Application runs without error and displays some number. But it's useless. When CEO sees that sum of salaries for last month is 6 million instead of 50 thousand (because of one new employee who is paid in South Korean Wons) the definition of a useful/useless output won't be discussed much.

Comment: The current system has no salary_currency column (we will imply that all the existing salary's are in a common currency).  We can't just add a salary in Wons here yet ... we need to roll out the change to add the column and set the currency on all the existing rows as first step. Then we need to roll out the application version that is aware of salary_currency and only after THAT are we truely able to add a salary in South Korean Won. You can do that in one step with an outage or you can do it in multiple steps without any outage.

Comment: Your answer: "I'd be interested to hear cases of breaking schema changes in the context of shared read-only schema's." I'm showing you how adding a column is a change across all readers. You say "roll out the application version" when the question and answer is clearly about microservices, dozen of them.

Comment: Fair enough. I think we see similar potential to get the same "Breakage" with an API if we view this as adding an attribute (existing clients need to take the additional attribute into account). Another way is to view this as changing the type from a scalar number to a compound type of number + currency (because the salary amount is now *dependant* on the currency / not just the PK). 

For an API we might promote a new API that uses the new type (currency + salary amount) noting that we still might have a "Breakage" with existing clients using the original API.

Answer (score 1):

It's not.

Reading data from a database "owned" by a different service is *not* bad. The microservices mantra says it's bad, in fact, it seems to have a bit of a cult following.

> why it is so bad to say that all database writes can only go through an API, [when] you are free to read directly from the databases of the various micro services.

It isn't bad.

> One could for example say that only a few ***database views*** are accessible outside the micro service so that the team maintaining the micro service know that as long as they keep these views intact then they can change the database structure of their micro service as much as they want.

That is perfectly valid. A VIEW is probably a better contract than an API; the RDBMS can enforce the security, instead of custom written code that might introduce a security vulnerability, and that only another programmer can analyse. A DBA can look at a VIEW and quickly assess whether the authorisations are configured correctly.

> Am I missing something here? Is there some other reason why data should only be read via an API?

Nothing missing, just an industry that is overzealous for new stuff. There is no good reason for reading via an API gateway, that's just a trend.

> Needless to say, my company is significantly smaller than Amazon (and always will be) and the maximum number of users we can ever have is about 5 million.

Many microservices projects fail because they are not Amazon, but they try to emulate their overengineering.

---

I have done a lot of research about Microservices, and while it's an incremental improvement on Service Oriented Architecture, it's not perfect.

From the leading answer [[back2dos]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/263745/edit):

> Databases are not very good at information hiding, which is quite
> plausible, because their job is to actually expose information.

There is a simple and mature mechanism in relational databases for this - the VIEW. The View is a stable contract about what data will be returned. The tables beneath the VIEW may change. The tables can be inaccessible, while the VIEW is accessible - and can be accomplished by-role. Perhaps VIEWs are not in fashion, but the capability is certainly there.

> You may even realize that you'd be better off with a document store or
> a graph database than with an RDBMS. If the data is encapsulated by a
> small API, you have a realistic chance to reimplement said API any way
> you need.

I remember thinking that an ORM was great because if you needed to change the database, you could do that easily. That practically never happens. You end up spending extra time on what-ifs that never happen. This is one of those what-ifs.

If you really do need to have a special-purpose data solution, it's highly likely that the database itself isn't the only change required, other components will also need to be changed anyway. No big deal. When you have a performance problem, do the work then. You'll only need to change that 1% of the system, and the rest of the 99% can succeed quite well in the relational database.

> You can transparently insert cache layers and what not.

Any API can implement cache layers. But it's better to just optimise your database in the first place. Whatever RAM you would allocate to REDIS, give that to Postgres. You can probably hold your whole DB in RAM.

From the second-top answer from [[itsbruce]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/263749/78712):

> What is more important and significant about a microservice: its API or its database schema? The API, because that is its contract with the rest of the world.

An API has a View-Model. What's the difference between a View-Model and a Data-Model? Extra unnecessary steps. A database can define a VIEW that can be consumed as a View-Model.

> The database schema is simply a convenient way of storing the data managed by the service, hopefully organised in a way that optimises the microservice´s performance.

That's probably the opposite of reality. Data is what the system is all about, not the microservice. The microservices are either mutating data, or gateways to data (read/write) or gateways to trigger mutations of data.

> The development team should be free to reorganise that schema

Reorganising the schema can happen freely behind a VIEW facade/contract.

> or switch to an entirely different datastore solution - at any time.

And give up a fundamental ability to easily JOIN data - at all times.

> The rest of the world should not care. The rest of the world cares when the API changes, because the API is the contract.

If you have to access data via an API, then perhaps, but why are we using custom-coded web services as gateways to databases again?

Answer (score 0):

State management (potentially a database) can be deployed in the Microservice's container and exposed via an API. The a Microservice's database is not visible to other systems outside the container - only the API. Alternatively you could have another service (e.g. a cache) manage state via an API.  Having all the Microservice's dependencies (other than API calls to other services) within a single deployable container is a key distinction in the architecture. If one does not get that go back and study the architecture.