Best Practices for Designing a Microservices System for Running and Managing Unit Tests
I am designing a microservices-based system to run unit tests on different computers, save the test results, and allow comments to be added to the results. I have a preliminary design in mind but would like feedback and suggestions for improvement or alternative approaches.
Proposed Design

Test Execution Service:
This service will handle the execution of tests, including load balancing and managing the distribution of tests across multiple computers.

Main Service:
This service will manage and store the test results, handle CRUD operations for entities, people could add tests and alternate the tests list here.


introducting to my challenges:
To ensure modularity, I want to design the system so that changes to one microservice (e.g., upgrading or restarting the Main Service) do not affect the running tests managed by the Test Execution Service.
However, this introduces challenges because:

How to handle shared models? Both microservices need to share data models, such as test lists and test results. Keeping these synchronized across services and ensuring consistency during CRUD operations is super complex? So what is like an best practices to do here? I feel like having a copy in each micro service is not something that most people do, although it is a pattern i was found about on the internet.

So I kinda got lost whether I should use database per service, or should I use like a central database for both of them, or me designing this system the way I described perhaps is the issue
I’d appreciate any insights or recommendations to help make this design more robust and scalable. Thank you!

We have a limit of one question per post. Can you [edit] your question to focus on a single problem?

Done @GregBurghardt thanks, do you have insights to share about my issue?

This question might be more what you are looking for: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/290922/118878

This question feels a bit confusing in the details. Is this a microservice architecture, or a server with local clients on the machines that connect to the server? Why would the test executor not be aware of the results of the tests it executes? What does the UI (and which pages it will have) have to do with the design considerations of your backend architecture? Why are you conflating database sharing with test run execution with UI design? I get the feeling this question is half-baked and requires further understanding of the requirements and the individual goals you're trying to achieve.

[..] Just to add to the questions that this raises: you're already trying to solve the problem of component outage and horizontal scaling of your microservices before you've even decided whether your microservices themselves own their own database. All of these are relevant considerations on their own but each requires a much more targeted approach, and not everything can be solved an answered in a single breath. Some of the underlying uncertainties that drive your questions are answered by most guidelines on e.g. microservices or distributed databases or scaling solutions.
